# vuetify change flex size in runtime

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I create a v-component jus like this:

```
<v-container grid-list-md >
  <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs10>
```

So now can I change in runtime the xs10 to xs5 for sample (I have 2 panels with one textfield in each, so when my user focus the text from first panel I need to increase his size xs6 to xs8 and decrease the other panel from xs6 to xs4 for sample

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can control the flexsize like this

```
<v-flex :xs10="true" :xs5="false">
```

So you can create a new data called `firstPanelFocus` for example,

```
 data() {
    return {
      firstPanelFocus: false
    };
  },
```

and for the v-flex

```
<v-flex :xs10="!firstPanelFocus" :xs5="firstPanelFocus">
```

Change the value of `firstPanelFocus` whenever user focus on(or blur from) a certain area

Comment: You can also use a class directly on v-flex and bind an object. `:class="{ 'xs10': hasfocus, 'xs5': !hasfocus}"`

Answer (score 6):

Starting from [Vue 2.6 (Macross)](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/vue-2-6-released-66aa6c8e785e) you can use **Dynamic Directive Arguments**!

For example:

```html
<v-flex :[dynamicFlex]="true">
  Some Text
</v-flex>
```

And in the vue instance:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    dynamicFlex: 'xs12'
  })
}
```

A full working example code can be found [here](https://github.com/Rolanddoda/vuetify-dynamic-flex-example/blob/master/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Comment: I love this solution, but I don't know how to get it working, if I use an object, like this: `<v-flex :[design.dynamicFlex.xs]="true"></v-flex>`. Any idea?

Comment: hmm that should with objects. Is the value of `design.dynamicFlex.xs` 'xs12' ?

Comment: Yes, but it looks like it fails on the dots, because when I inspect the element, I see that it printed `[design`

Comment: In order to make it work you can create a computed property which returns `design.dynamicFlex.xs`